# Why I am getting below error while I am writing a code in scala to run a spark application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}


object simpleSpark extends App {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf.setMaster("local")
    sparkConf.setAppName("First Application")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)


    val file = sc.textFile("datasets/movieratings.txt")
    val ratings = file.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
    val result = ratings.countByValue()
}
```

Environment:

- OS: Windows
- IDE: IntelliJ

Also could you please let me know is this the right way to specify the file path 
in code(after textfile)?

Error: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

[image]

Comment: What's the `/*` supposed to be good for?

Comment: Could you please share , how your `movieRatings` file looks like

Comment: The error probably is because some line of your input file does not contain a third _"column"_ separated by `\t`. Without seeing the file is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

It says you're getting an array index out of bounds error. You don't have line numbers, but I suspect the offending line is

```
val ratings = file.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
```

The likely cause of the error is that you have a line with one or fewer tabs, split it into an array with no index 2, then try to access the non-existent element at index 2. It may be helpful to remember that arrays are 0 indexed, so index 2 actually refers to the third item. Additionally, if you expect at least 3 items and this isn't an off by one error, then you need to do a cleaning pass to make sure you're not getting any non-conformant data.